# How to run tools in php server at same time

Tags: c#, php, r, batch-file, xampp

I am running a web portal on a xampp (win 7) server running on cloud.

- User uploads an .xlsx file which is saved to a folder
- User picks a date and options which will be used later
- User clicks submit button which calls a form automatic.php
- This form will call 2 separate tools 1 in C# another in R

  ```
  <form action="tools/automatic.php" method="post" target="_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  ```

> automatic.php

- Uses user submitted information to build 2 .bat files with the following format:

> presentation.bat

```
START "" "C:\Tools\1\Presentation.exe" 2019 01 25 00 templatename users\thisfolder "inputfile.xlsx"
exit
```

> analytics.bat

```
R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore "--args 2019 01 25 00 templatename users\thisfolder" C:\Tools\2\analytics.R analytics.out &
```

Then, it calls those 2 .bats like this

> run R

```
$Rbatpath = 'C:\NPOSL\\' .$userDirectory.'\analytics.bat';
$Rcomand= exec($Rbatpath);
pclose(popen("start " . $Rcomand, "r"));
```

> run C

```
$batpath = 'C:\NPOSL\\'.$userDirectorytunnel.'\presentation.bat';
$Ccomand= exec($batpath);
pclose(popen("start " . $Ccomand, "r"));

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.close();</script>";
```

This is working without issues, and I am aware it is not the best way to handle it.

- It calls the R tool and runs it for 30 seconds.
- After those 30 seconsd call C# tool and runs it for 20 seconds
- After those 20 seconds closes window

**I need it to run both tools at same time**

I've been searching stackoverflow for many hours now and tried every possible combination of

- Writing "start" in php, but not in .bat ( and )vice-versa,
- I've tried to not even create a .bat and execute the tools directly from exec()
- add /B to try and run on background

No matter what I try, even though it works with no issues, always waits for everything to finish

**Can you please help me running everything at same time?**

Ideally I would like the tools to finish before closing window, but that is superfluous and I don't really care if its not possible.

---

**EDIT**

I changed it to be:

```
$Ccomand = exec("the content which was inside .bat" . " > /dev/null &")
```

and it still waits for execution to finish.

Comment: your problem is how your using exec() "If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends." so just `exec ($Rbatpath . " > /dev/null &");` assuming you are ok just trowing away the output

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I changed it so that $comand is "exec("content which was inside .bat" . "> /dev/null &"); and it still waits for execution to be finished. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Why do you need to creatr 2 batch files? Create one and simply seperate the commands by pipe. I.e `START "" "C:\Tools\1\Presentation.exe" 2019 01 25 00 templatename users\thisfolder "inputfile.xlsx" | R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore "--args 2019 01 25 00 templatename users\thisfolder" C:\Tools\2\analytics.R analytics.out &` be careful though as batch might see that last `&` as a batch seperator, maybe escape it `^&`

Answer (score 0):

Can you combine the two batch file contents into one?

The problem is with `exec()` which runs processes asynchronously.

What happens if you circumvent this with `pclose(popen("start ".$Rbatpath,"r"))` or `$Rcommand = "start ".$Rbatpath; pclose(popen($Rbatpath,"r"))`?